# Efficient way to compute scores within data.table by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table` and I am looking to calculate by group (`id`) the smallest (`min`) jarowinkler score by all other members of that group. I have a simple nested loop that can compute this, though looking for a more efficient method.

```
library(data.table)
# install.packages("stringdist")
library(stringdist)

# Create `data.table`
dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                var = c("a","a","kyle","kyle","kile","rage","page","cage","","asd","fdd","xzx"))

# Add a numeric empty score variable         
dt[, "score" := as.numeric()]       
# Create a unique id within each group         
dt[, uid := sequence(.N), by = id]

dt
#     id  var score uid
#  1:  1    a    NA   1
#  2:  1    a    NA   2
#  3:  2 kyle    NA   1
#  4:  2 kyle    NA   2
#  5:  2 kile    NA   3
#  6:  3 rage    NA   1
#  7:  3 page    NA   2
#  8:  3 cage    NA   3
#  9:  3         NA   4
# 10:  4  asd    NA   1
# 11:  4  fdd    NA   2
# 12:  4  xzx    NA   3
```

The current, but slow method:

```
# Loop over all unique id's
for(i in unique(dt$id)){
   # Loop over each member and compute lowest stringdist 
   for(j in 1:nrow(dt[id == i])){
        dt[id == i & uid == j, "score" := min(stringdist(dt[id == i & uid == j, var], 
                                              dt[id == i & uid != j, var],
                                              method = "jw"))]
    }
}

dt[]
#     id  var     score uid
#  1:  1    a 0.0000000   1
#  2:  1    a 0.0000000   2
#  3:  2 kyle 0.0000000   1
#  4:  2 kyle 0.0000000   2
#  5:  2 kile 0.1666667   3
#  6:  3 rage 0.1666667   1
#  7:  3 page 0.1666667   2
#  8:  3 cage 0.1666667   3
#  9:  3      1.0000000   4
# 10:  4  asd 0.4444444   1
# 11:  4  fdd 0.4444444   2
# 12:  4  xzx 1.0000000   3
```

Comment: First of all, (without looking at the function itself) `for(i in unique(dt$id))` is redundant, this is why you have the `, by = ` part in data.table

Comment: Second of all, if you have duplicate words in a single group, you should only calculate for unique combinations. Also, `stringdist` accepts vectors so you don't need to run per row (at least not always).

Answer (score 2):

(On second thoughts, this is actually very close to David's comments) A possible approach:

```
#create combinations of unique var by group then call stringdist once
jw <- dt[, if (uniqueN(var)>1) transpose(combn(unique(var), 2, simplify=FALSE)), .(id)][,
    dis := stringdist(V1, V2, "jw")]

#find the min distance for each word
lu <- rbindlist(list(jw[, .(mdis=min(dis)), .(id, var=V1)], 
    jw[, .(mdis=min(dis)), .(id, var=V2)]))

#update join on the min distance for each word
dt[lu, on=.(var, id), score := mdis]

#for duplicated words, dist is 0
dt[dt[, .I[duplicated(var) | duplicated(var, fromLast=TRUE)], by=.(id)]$V1,
    score := 0]
```

Motivation: Since `stringdist` is already built for speed and runs in parallel by using 'openMP' (from manual), it will faster if you run the `stringdist` once rather than multiple times by group.

Comment: You shouldn't have made it a community wiki just because of few comments. Writing the code is much harder than just speculate. Regarding your last line, I think you could just initiate with `dt[, score := 0]` and the just update everything that isn't a dupe perhaps?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it would not work for `kyle` as it would have some value beforehand. i just thought its the etiquette not to plagiarize someone's idea